# Async syntax in ES7

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, ecmascript-5

How to convert the following method to an async method (syntax-wise):

```
const download = function(url, dest, callback){
    request.get(url)
    .on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)} )
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./voices/${dest}`))
    .on('close', callback);
};
```

This syntax isn't correct:

```
async function download(function(url, dest, callback)){
    request.get(url)
    .on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)} )
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./voices/${dest}`))
    .on('close', callback);
};
```

because `function(url, dest, callabck)` isn't recognized as a function.

Comment: `async` is ES2017, not ES6, hence the problem.

Comment: My bad. I'm using async methods in other places, it's just this particular syntax that I'm stuck at!

Comment: your `download` function is not syntatically correct.

Comment: What do you think `download(function(url, dest, callback))` will do?

Answer (score 1):

You use async when you want to await a function. In this case what you want is to return a Promise so that a method can call and await it's execution:

```
const download = (url, dest) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(url)
      .on('error', reject)
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./voices/${dest}`))
      .on('close', resolve);
  });
};
```

Now you can use that function with `await`, usage:

```
async function somewhere() {
  try {
    await download('http://.../', 'dest');
    // code when completed
  }
  catch (err) {
    // code when error
  }
}
```

See more:

- [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
- [ES8 async/await](https://medium.com/@_bengarrison/javascript-es8-introducing-async-await-functions-7a471ec7de8a)
- [async/await tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9)
- [async/await explained](https://tutorialzine.com/2017/07/javascript-async-await-explained)